# Selenium grid - node chrome - Vstest - failed to navigate to URL

Tags: selenium-webdriver, azure-aks, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, vstest, selenium-hub

Performing selenium tests in selenium grid - selenium node-chrome environment using azure release pipelines.

respective yaml files are provided below , on the release pipelines VSTests logs getting error as failed to navigate URL, looks like selenium grid unable to open URL

TestContext Messages:
Failed to navigate to URL: https://www.google.com

```yaml
--- 
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  labels: 
    app: selenium-hub
  name: selenium-hub
spec: 
  replicas: 1
  selector: 
    matchLabels: 
      app: selenium-hub
  template: 
    metadata: 
      labels: 
        app: selenium-hub
    spec: 
      containers: 
        - 
          env: 
            - 
              name: newSessionWaitTimeout
              value: "-1"
            - 
              name: cleanUpCycle
              value: "4000"
            - 
              name: role
              value: hub
            - 
              name: throwOnCapabilityNotPresent
              value: "true"
          image: "selenium/hub:3.141.59"
          livenessProbe: 
            httpGet: 
              path: /wd/hub/status
              port: 4444
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 5
            timeoutSeconds: 1
          name: selenium-hub
          ports: 
            - 
              containerPort: 4444
          readinessProbe: 
            httpGet: 
              path: /wd/hub/status
              port: 4444
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 5
            timeoutSeconds: 1
      nodeSelector: 
        beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: selenium-hub
  labels:
    app: selenium-hub
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 4444
    targetPort: 4444
    name: port0
  selector:
    app: selenium-hub
  type: LoadBalancer
  sessionAffinity: None
---
--- 
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  labels: 
    app: selenium-node-chrome
  name: selenium-node-chrome
spec: 
  replicas: 60
  selector: 
    matchLabels: 
      app: selenium-node-chrome
  template: 
    metadata: 
      labels: 
        app: selenium-node-chrome
    spec: 
      containers: 
        - 
          env: 
            - 
              name: HUB_HOST
              value: selenium-hub
            - 
              name: HUB_PORT
              value: "4444"
            - 
              name: NODE_MAX_INSTANCES
              value: "2"
            - 
              name: NODE_MAX_SESSION
              value: "4"
            - 
              name: nodeStatusCheckTimeout
              value: "8000"
            - 
              name: nodePolling
              value: "5000"
            - 
              name: role
              value: node
            - 
              name: browserTimeout
              value: "300"
            - 
              name: timeout
              value: "300"
            - 
              name: unregisterIfStillDownAfter
              value: "60000"
            - 
              name: downPollingLimit
              value: "2"
              
          image: "selenium/node-chrome:3.141.59-krypton"
          name: selenium-node-chrome
          ports: 
            - 
              containerPort: 5555
      nodeSelector: 
        beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
```